# Android getting ready to publish

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have used my main.xml and the layout manager to test if my app fit on all available sizes via the pulldown menu (except 2.7) in the layout manager.

I have not run emulators with all these sizes but is that necessary seeing they fit in the layout manager?

Also reffering to the supported screen sizes here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html it seems from 1.6 on they are all set to true by default.So is this the correct syntax I should put in the manifest.xml?

```
<manifest "STUFF">
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens=["false"] 
                      android:normalScreens=["true"] 
                      android:largeScreens=["true"] 
                      android:anyDensity=["true"] />
</manifest>
```

Just want to be sure I am targeting all available devices here.Am I missing anything before I launch this first app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's just

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false" 
                  android:normalScreens="true" 
                  android:largeScreens="true" 
                  android:anyDensity="true" />
```

I would run your app in the emulator with the different screen sizes personally.

Comment: I have not figured out how to change which emulator to use is really why i have not tested in all the emulators heh.Is there an easy way to switch emulators?

Comment: Hmm.. so I think if you go to Eclipse and click Window -> Android SDK and AVD manager, you can see a list of virtual devices.  You can add and edit them there. I think you just add a new one with the screen size you want.